# Why is PHP move_uploaded_file() failing to open stream?

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm down to the most basic move and still struggling with it:

```
$path = '/home/*NAME*/public_html/ih/upload/';
$fileName = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

echo $path, "<br />"; echo $fileName;

move_uploaded_file($fileName, $path);
```

Both path and filename print the expected contents before the move fails.  The path is identical to what I get when I echo getcwd() in the directory I want to move the files to.  I've chmodded the upload folder and all subdirectories to 777 to be safe.

My error messages are:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(/home/*NAME*/public_html/ih/upload/) 
[function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Is a directory in /home/*NAME*/public_html/ih/upload.php on line 11

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: 
Unable to move '/tmp/phph4oYFN' to '/home/*NAME*/public_html/ih/upload/' in /home/*NAME*/public_html/ih/upload.php on line 11
```

Does anyone know what I could do to fix this? Is it a permissions error? Thank you if so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The clue is here:

```
[function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Is a directory...
```

You've passed a directory path as an argument to `move_uploaded_file()`. You need to pass a filename.

Perhaps you want

```
move_uploaded_file($fileName, $path.$fileName);
```

This won't handle duplicate names well, though.